# How to view ms word documents in android

Tags: java, android

how to view ms word documents in android without using any third party applications like 'Thinkfreeoffice'.Apoche POI has library for reading ms word documents which or in .doc format(old formats) but my problem is I am unable to view .docx (latest formats).so anyone of you please provide some information.I am working on this issue from last four days but still no results.

Comment: Can you just convert the word document to a pdf?

Comment: but I am not getting any third party open source libraries.If you know the solutions or libraries please tell me.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Apache POI should be able to read all kinds of word documents (OLE2 and OOXML formats); so what exactly is your problem with docx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI is able to read all kinds of word documents (OLE2 and OOXML formats, .doc and .docx extensions respectively).

If your docx document doesn't work, try:

1. A more simple document
2. Make sure you can open it in Word (maybe the file got corrupted somehow when it was transferred on your mobile phone)
3. Try a more recent version of Apache POI.
4. Try to convert the document on your desktop just to see if you get any errors.

Comment: I found this link http://www.openxml4j.org/ from this link http://poi.apache.org/oxml4j/index.html by following your above  points.But I am not getting any help related to my problem.Could you please provide details information.Thanks for your response.

Comment: OpenXML4J is outdated since 2008 when it was merged with POI. Don't try to use it. Use the normal POI JARs instead.

Comment: but with Apachi POI how can I view .dcox files?

Comment: Just convert them to HTML or PDF or text.

Comment: I searched in that scenario also but I didn't get any solution for .docx format to other formats.I you know any libraries please tell me.Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Read my answer again. POI supports docx. If it doesn't work for you, then **you** must be doing something wrong. As long as you ignore my comments and suggestions, there is no point to continue this.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't provide native support for Android to view Microsoft format office documents.
That means you have to use third party apps. Some vendors, like Samsung, provide Polaris Office, but that's a third party app, too. It just comes bundled with the phone.

Comment: Using Apoche POI we can convert doc file to html and we can load that html in webview.So I am thinking that we can read ms word documents.But I am unable to convert .docx files to html.Thanks for your response.